# Show specific forms when specific buttons are clicked using loop

Tags: vb.net

I want to show specific forms when specific buttons are clicked. I am wondering if this is possible to do by using a loop.

Here is my code so far:

```
 Private Sub ShowTable()
        Me.Hide()
        If btnClicked = 1 Then
            Table1.Show()
        ElseIf btnClicked = 2 Then
            Table2.Show()
        ElseIf btnClicked = 3 Then
            Table2.Show()
        End If
```

I've declared an Integer which is set to 0 and it changes as certain buttons are clicked.

It it possible to make it easier by using a loop and have it return the value? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why are you specifically in need of a LOOP.? are you going to display multiple items in a single click.?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Why do you think that a loop helps to determine which form you want to show?

Comment: I just want to display the correct form when a specific button is clicked. I thought using if statements here can be slower than using, say, a loop.

Comment: No Loop required in your case.! may be you can shorten your code.! if so add your button click event's code with this question.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to use my current code. Thank you for the help anyway!